# Save Google Maps polygon overlay into oracle using php

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3, oracle10g

I am following the tutorial of google maps to save overlays to mysql: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3 but I cant achieve it with Oracle. If someone can point my errors, this is my code so far:

```
function savePolygons(){
    for (var i = 0; i < createdShapes.length; i++){

        var nom_zone  = document.getElementById('nom_zone_' + createdShapes[i].id).value;
        alert(nom_zone)
        var couleur = createdShapes[i].fillColor;
        alert(couleur)
        var code_cs = '711';
        var shapeid_export = createdShapes[i].id;
        alert(shapeid_export)
        var geometry = createdShapes[i].getPath().getArray();
        alert(geometry)
        var url1 = "oracle_savePolygons.php?nom_zone=" + nom_zone + "&couleur=" + couleur + "&code_cs=" + code_cs + "&shapeid_export=" + shapeid_export + "&geometry=" + geometry;
        downloadUrl(url1, function(data, responseCode){
          if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <= 1) {
            infowindow.close();
          }
        });
    }
}

function downloadUrl(url1, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request.responseText, request.status);
     }
  };

  request.open('GET', url1, true);
  request.send(null);
 }

 function doNothing() {}
```

there is the php code of oracle_savePolygons.php, Im using EasyPHP on localhost:

```
<?php
require("oracle_dbinfo.php");

$nom_zone =$_GET['nom_zone'];
$shapeid_export = $_GET['shapeid_export'];
$code_cs = $_GET['code_cs'];
$couleur = $_GET['couleur'];
$geometry = $_GET['geometry'];

$conn = oci_connect($username, $password, $database);

$query = oci_parse($conn, 'INSERT INTO test1 (shapeid, nom_zone, code_cs, couleur, geometry) VALUES (:nom_zone, :shapeid_export, :code_cs, :couleur, :geometry)';
oci_bind_by_name($query, ":nom_zone", $nom_zone);
oci_bind_by_name($query, ":shapeid_export", $shapeid_export);
oci_bind_by_name($query, ":code_cs", $code_cs);
oci_bind_by_name($query, ":couleur", $couleur);
oci_bind_by_name($query, ":geometry", $geometry);

oci_execute($query);
oci_commit($conn);
?>
```

I have found another solution which is:

```
function savePolygons(){
   for (var i = 0; i < createdShapes.length; i++){
    var nom_zone  = escape(document.getElementById('nom_zone_' + createdShapes[i].id).value);
    var couleur = escape(createdShapes[i].fillColor);
    var code_cs = escape('711');
    var shapeid_export = escape(createdShapes[i].id);
    var geometry = createdShapes[i].getPath().getArray();
    var url1 = "oracle_savePolygons.php?nom_zone=" + nom_zone + "&couleur=" + couleur + "&code_cs=" + code_cs + "&shapeid_export=" + shapeid_export + "&geometry=" + geometry;
    window.location.href = url1 ;
   }
}
```

Its working, but I wonder if using window.location.href is a safe solution. I have also problems with inserting the geometry array in the oracle GEOMETRY CLOB var of test1 table. I have an oci_execute error and I dont know why. Is a varchar of 4000 bytes is large enough for polygon geometries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the next code to get the cooridinates and then I pass them to a field for processing it in a form.

```
function draw() { 
 if (drawingManager <= 0) then 

var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
      drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
      drawingControl: true,
      drawingControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
        drawingModes: [
         // google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
          //google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
          google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
         // google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
         // google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
        ]
      },
      markerOptions: {
        icon: 'images/beachflag.png'
      },
      polygonOptions: {
        fillColor: '#1E90FF',
        fillOpacity: 0.4,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        clickable: true,
        editable: true,
        zIndex: 1
      }
    });


    var coord_listener = google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
    var coordinates = (polygon.getPath().getArray());


    alert(coordinates);
    grabarPoligonoMysql(coordinates);
    window.poly = polygon;
});



    drawingManager.setMap(map);


} 

function PassPolygonToField(coordinates) {
//here I pass the coords to the form field and then I insert the form into a mysql database.
document.getElementById('myField').value = (coordinates);

}
```

Comment: thank you, your post was useful to me for getting the coordinates with the getPath().getArray()

Comment: another question. how do you reconstruct the polygon with the array of coordinates. I have a string like this in my db (45.234234, -74.23424),(45.234266,-74.23423424)....

Comment: I m in the same issue than you, and I post the question but anyone has answer yet. I thought about to split the chain using asp but what I have thought much better is doing with circles instead than with polygons, getting the coordinates Center and the radious of the circle.

Comment: I think I have found a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13982161/1914034 I will test it today.