# use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse to store polygon coordinates into oracle

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3

I want to store the coordinates of a google maps polygon overlay into oracle and display it on next session. There is the code:

```
function savePolygons(){
    $.post('oracle_deletePolygons.php');
    for (var i = 0; i < createdShapes.length; i++){
        var nom_zone  = escape(document.getElementById('nom_zone_' + createdShapes[i].id).value);
        var couleur = escape(createdShapes[i].fillColor);
        var code_cs = escape('711');
        var shapeid_export = escape(createdShapes[i].id);
        var geometry = createdShapes[i].getPath().getArray();
        geometry = JSON.stringify(geometry);
        var url1 = "oracle_savePolygons.php?nom_zone=" + nom_zone + "&couleur=" + couleur + "&code_cs=" + code_cs + "&shapeid_export=" + shapeid_export + "&geometry=" + geometry;
        $.get(url1);
    }   
}
```

I use JSON.stringify to convert into text the path array of the polygon which return this:

```
[{"Ya":53.4357192066942,"Za":-75.82763671875},{"Ya":52.40241887397331,"Za":-77.3876953125},{"Ya":51.781435604431195,"Za":-74.0478515625}]
```

After using php to parse the data of the oracle table into javascript var, I use JSON.parse to convert the string back to array of coordinates like that in order to rebuild the polygons:

```
function addPolygons(shapeId_import, nom_zone, couleur, geometry){
    geometry = JSON.parse(geometry);
    var newPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: geometry,
        fillColor: couleur,
        fillOpacity: 0.45,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        editable: false,
        shapeid: shapeId_import,
        map:map
    });
```

Unfortunately, its not working. I cant rebuild polygon with this new array. Can you tell me how to rebuild the polygon that way?

Comment: And your question is.....?

Comment: Are you sure `geometry` is what you think it is? Is it a string containing JSON? What's the error?

Comment: geometry is the var in which I store the coordinates of each vertices of the polygon with this method: var geometry = createdShapes[i].getPath().getArray();

Comment: I mean in the `addPolygons` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON.stringify() will not keep the original MVCArray, the constructor is missing.

You better use `google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath()` to create a storable value and decode it before re-using it.

Comment: thank you very much, I was thinking about using latlng() but your solution seems better! I'll try it tomorrow. Happy Holydays!